# Transform my program in loop but it is in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, while-loop

I have a program with 1 array of 381 elements. I have to highlight the elements according to their character size but I did like this :

```html
print "Nombre de handle avec 2 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 2 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 3 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 3 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 4 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 4 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 5 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 5 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 6 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 6 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 7 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 7 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 8 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 8 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 9 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 9 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 10 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 10 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 11 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 11 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 12 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 12 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 13 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 13 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 14 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 14 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 15 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 15 }
    print "Nombre de handle avec 16 caractères : "
    puts jnr.count { |w| w.length == 16 }
```

but I would like to know if it was possible to reduce it to a loop but knowing that it is in an array the values ​​are quite special and when I try "while" it does not work.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `group_by(&:length)` on the array of words you have which will create a hash of words with same length grouped by the same key then iterate through the hash and print accordingly

```rb
hash  = jnr.group_by(&:length)
hash.each do |length, arr_of_words|
  puts "Nombre de handle avec #{length} caractères : #{arr_of_words.count}"
end
```

#### Example:

```rb
[4] pry(main)> hash = ["Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda", "XXX", "YYY"].group_by(&:length)
=> {5=>["Volvo", "Mazda"], 3=>["BMW", "XXX", "YYY"], 4=>["Ford"]}
[5] pry(main)> hash.each do |length, arr_of_words|
[5] pry(main)*   puts "Nombre de handle avec #{length} caractères : #{arr_of_words.count}"
[5] pry(main)* end
Nombre de handle avec 5 caractères : 2
Nombre de handle avec 3 caractères : 3
Nombre de handle avec 4 caractères : 1
```